# Parsing file and command line options in a same way

Tags: java

I wrote a script in `Java` (not sure if it's the write term) .
User can specify env variables with two ways: command line or in a file.
The command line looks as follows (separated with `~~~`)

```
ENV1=1~~~ENV2=String2
```

The file looks as follows:

```
setenv ENV1 1
setenv ENV2 String2
```

I wrote a function which returns a collection of the envs (so the output is: `{ENV2=String2, ENV1=1}`).
It looks as following:

```
public Map<String, String> getEnvs() {
    final String envArg = getOption(cmdNames.ENV); // returns the path or the command-line options
    if (null != envArg && !"".equals(envArg) && envArg.contains("=")) {
        final String varArray[] = envArg.split("~~~"); // split by a special string
        final Map<String, String> new_vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (final String var : varArray) {
            final String varName = var.split("=")[0];
            String varValue = var.split("=")[1];
            if (!varValue.contains("\"") && varValue.contains(" ")) {
                varValue = "\"" + varValue + "\"";
            }
            new_vars.put(varName, varValue);
        }
        return new_vars;
    }
    return null;
}
```

For now, I wrote a function for command-line options. I would like to add support for the file option. The problem is that those options have different appearance - one of them I need to split by `~~~` while the other one by `setenv`.
I would be more than glad to hear some suggestion on how to add support for the file option in the same `getEnvs` function.
I already have some implementation in my head but it gets messy and I'm looking for the cleanest way possible. (As I understand, we need to insert data from a file into an array and split it by `setenv` but we also need to split between `name` and `value` - it feels the code can be used twice but I'm not sure which part should do the trick).

Comment: I'd suggest creating two helper methods: `getEnvsFromArgs` and `getEnvsFromFile.` If the arg is set, delegate to the first in `getEnvs`. If the file is set, delegate to the second.

Comment: @jokster is it not a duplication of a code? how should `getEnvsFromFile` look like?

Comment: It would only be a duplication if the two methods would be the same. But as you said yourself, the lines look different! You would read the file and process each line to fill the map.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you seem to be trying to tackle seems to be best handled by the strategy pattern.

The content of the file and the command line can both be represented by strings. These strings can be processed by some type of parser which can use different strategies depending on what you wish to do.

It would look something like this

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException{
    boolean parseFromFile = true; //whatever criteria you want to use
    String content;
    Parser p;
    String fileName = "yikes";
    if(parseFromFile){
        p = new Parser(new FileParseStrategy());
        //we need to read contents of file prior to parsing
        content = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    }
    else {
        p = new Parser(new CmdLineParseStrategy());
        content = getContent(cmdNames.ENV); //just coping what you used.
    }
    Map<String, String> vars = p.run(content);
}

public class Parser{
    final ParseStrategy parseStrategy;

    public Parser(ParseStrategy ps) {
        this.parseStrategy = ps;
    }

    public Map<String, String> run(String input){
        return parseStrategy.parse(input);
    }
}

public interface ParseStrategy {
    Map<String, String> parse(String input);
}

public class FileParseStrategy implements ParseStrategy{

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> parse(String input) {
        Map<String, String>  result = new HashMap<>();
        for(String line : input.split("\r?\n|\r")) {
            String[] parts = validate(line.split(" "));
            result.put(parts[1], parts[2]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String[] validate(String[] parts) {
        if(parts.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("3 parts needed");
        }
        if(!parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setenv")){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unrecognized cmd");
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
//given implementation of parsing from command line.
public class CmdLineParseStrategy implements ParseStrategy {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> parse(String envArg) {
        if (null != envArg && !"".equals(envArg) && envArg.contains("=")) {
            final String varArray[] = envArg.split("~~~"); // split by a special string
            final Map<String, String> new_vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (final String var : varArray) {
                final String varName = var.split("=")[0];
                String varValue = var.split("=")[1];
                if (!varValue.contains("\"") && varValue.contains(" ")) {
                    varValue = "\"" + varValue + "\"";
                }
                new_vars.put(varName, varValue);
            }
            return new_vars;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```